# set $value in sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList

Tags: symfony1, symfony-plugins

Actually I am using the sfFormExtraPlugin in symfony 1.4.4

I am using the class widget sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList, all seems fine but when I open the form again in edit mode, There is nothing in associated select box.

So, My question is How to fill associated values in that box using sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList widget?

I checked the database & values are present there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourWidget->setDefault($values);
```

Values is an array with the values selected.

Good luck!!